# Can't get TinyMCE to pick up my own CSS file

Tags: tinymce

I have followed the instructions here
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:content_css
and created my own CSS file in my Apps root folder,  referenced it using

```
   tinyMCE.init({
    content_css : "mycontent.css",
```

but it never gets picked up. 
We are using TinyMCE '3.5.6'   If I make changes to the content.css file these are picked up ok so it's not a caching issue.  Any ideas on what else to try?

Comment: Is the file you are running tinymce on in your apps root folder as well?

Comment: yes, same location.  I looked in the tiny MCE Editor_Template file and all it appears to do is check if content_css is == false and if so it does not load the default content.css file,  otherwiae it always loads it. It does not look for the file content_css points to ,  .......    if (ed.settings.content_css !== false)
            {
                ed.contentCSS.push(ed.baseURI.toAbsolute(url + "/skins/" + ed.settings.skin + "/content.css");
            } ......  so I have no idea what the Documentation is talking about, me thinks it's a feature coming down the line

Comment: did you try this using a full URI